# TimedOut Exception rises during sending requests

Tags: python, symfony

I am very new in programming. Sorry if my question is stupid! But may  be someone can explain me this process. And sorry for my english!

I try to send a pool of requests to some server with python grequests component and have a timedOut exception. If I send a very small pool of requests(about 500) it works fine and very fast, but if I increase this pool I get the exception. It's a very simple code:

```
import grequests
import time
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

start_time = time.time()
urls // list of urls
rs = (grequests.get(u) for u in urls)

# Send them.
grequests.map(rs)
print(time.time() - start_time)
```

Also I tried to do it with symfony framework and it's process component.
When I run it consequentially with run() method all is good but it takes a lot of time to send all requests. If I use start() method and send requests asynchronously the same exception is risen. My code:

```
public function someFunction($id, $interval, $url)
{

    $startTime = time();
    $end = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
    $start = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($end) - $interval);
    echo 'interval: ' . $start . ' - ' . $end . PHP_EOL;
    $data = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:UserAccount',      'slave')-> ...;
    if (empty($data)) {
        $response = false;
    } else {
        echo count($data);
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($data as $item) {
           $fullUrl = sprintf($url, $item['a'], $item['b']);
           $process = new Process("wget -o --spider --timeout=3 --tries=1 $fullUrl > /dev/null 2> /dev/null || true");
           $process->setTimeout(30);
           $process->start();
           $i++;
           if ($i == 10) {
              $process->wait();
              $i = 0;
           }
           echo $process->getPid() . PHP_EOL;
        }
        $response = true;
     }
     $endTime = time();
     echo "Time spent" . ($endTime - $startTime)/60 . " minutes. And delivered ". count($data) . PHP_EOL;
     return $response;
}
```

Also if I increase timeOut it doesn't help. Script works until timeOut limit and exception rises again. And small pools of requests are sent well.

I appriciate any help! May be someone can advise me where I can read about sending requests stap by stap?

Comment: python is good for this kind of job, try multithreading. define a method in multi threading way which accept one url as a parameter. generate multiple threads from you loop of urls list. see  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

Comment: Please take extra care with handling that `$url` or you might end up with arbitrary core execution...

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped a little. I solved the problem of timeout exception and it works fine with localhost. But while not so well with remote server. I think I need deeper understanding in multi threading.